# How to use SHA256 in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sha256

How to simplely convert a string to SHA256 string in Node.js.
And convert a SHA256 string to a normal string?

```
const shajs = require('sha.js');



console.log('starts');
const code = 'WEASDSAEWEWAEAWEAWEWA';
const normal = 'anne';
const encrypted = shajs('sha256')
    .update(normal)
    .digest('hex');
const unencrypted = shajs('sha256')
    .read(normal)
    .toString('hex');
console.log(normal);
console.log(encrypted);
console.log(unencrypted);
console.log('end');
```

Where should i put the HASH CODE?

Comment: What do you mean by hash code?

Comment: Do you understand that SHA256 is a one-way hash?  You can't convert it back to a normal string.  Also, in node.js see https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hash which is built-in.

Comment: In the other language i used SHA256 i've create a HASH CODE to transform the passwords
#define HASH_CODE = 'WEASDSAEWEWAEAWEAWEWA';
SHA256_PassHash(inputtext, HASH_CODE, password, 64);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHA256 is a one-way hash function which means you can only convert a string into a hash value not its reverse. To check password, you need to rehash plain password and compare it with the one you already stored in database.